# got error in Tomcat server log Parse Error at line 164 column 11: The content of element type "web-app" must match

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am getting error in tomcat server log can someone help on this.And please tell me what action need to be taken.

```
2016-01-21 01:46:37,370 INFO  - ApplicationManager.LoadApplicationFactory:
  com.gft.rpdb.service.webflow.WebflowAppFactoryImpl
2016-01-21 01:46:42,958 INFO  - RpdbImportProvider Init on Port ... 1099   
2016-01-21 01:46:43,178 INFO  - RpdbImportProvider Ready.   
2016-01-21 01:46:43,211 INFO  - ControllerFilterServlet.Init: Proxy for batch services disabled.','false    
2016-01-21 01:46:43,212 INFO  - ControllerFilterServlet.Init:  InitFinished ,'Framework started' 
2016-01-21 01:46:55,259 ERROR - Parse Error at line 164 column 11: The
     content of element type "web-app" must match
     "(icon?,display-name?,description?,distributable?,
      context- param*,filter*,filter-mapping*,listener*,servlet*,
      servlet-mapping*,session-config?,mime-mapping*,welcome-file-list?,
      error-page*,taglib*,resource-env-ref*,resource-ref*,security-constraint*,
      login-config?,security-role*,env-entry*,ejb-ref*,ejb-local-ref*)".
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "web-app" must match
  ....
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
  ....
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
  ....
```

## web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>ControllerFilter</filter-name>
      <display-name>ControllerFilterServlet</display-name>
      <description>This the MVC Controller for the site.</description>
      <filter-class>com.gft.rpdb.web.ControllerFilterServlet</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>configFile</param-name>
         <param-value>WEB-INF/fwk/framework-config.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>urlBase</param-name>
         <param-value>http://repackp1.uk.db.com:9670/rpdb/</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>proxy-enabled</param-name>
         <param-value>false</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>proxy-host-address</param-name>
         <param-value>_PROXY_HOST_ADDRESS_</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>proxy-host-port</param-name>
         <param-value>_PROXY_HOST_PORT_</param-value>
      </init-param>
   </filter>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>UploadFilter</filter-name>
      <display-name>UploadFilterServlet</display-name>
      <description>FilterServlet responsible of performing file uploads.</description>
      <filter-class>com.gft.rpdb.web.UploadFilterServlet</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>maxRequestSize</param-name>
         <param-value>10000000</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>tempDirectory</param-name>
         <param-value>WEB-INF/fwk/tmp</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>maxMemorySize</param-name>
         <param-value>0</param-value>
      </init-param>
   </filter>
  <filter>
      <filter-name>WebServiceFilter</filter-name>
      <display-name>WebServiceFilter</display-name>
      <description>FilterServlet responsible of Webservices.</description>
      <filter-class>com.gft.rpdb.web.WebServiceFilterServlet</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>dirFile</param-name>
         <param-value>WEB-INF/fwk/config/webservice/</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>propertiesFile</param-name>
         <param-value>webservices.properties</param-value>
      </init-param>
      </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>UploadFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>ControllerFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>WebServiceFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
        <!--
                servlet> <servlet-name>restcommander</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>com.gft.rpdb.app.batch.RestCommander</servlet-class>
                </servlet> <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>restcommander</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/restcommander</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping
        -->
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
        </session-config>

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
                <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
                <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                <param-name>axis2.xml.path</param-name>
                <param-value>/apps/repack/rpdb-conf/axis2.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
       <!-- init-param>
                <param-name>axis2.repository.path</param-name>
                <param-value>WEB-INF/repository</param-value>
        </init-param-->
        <!--<param-name>axis2.repository.url</param-name>-->
        <!--<param-value>http://localhot/myrepo</param-value>-->
        <!--<param-name>axis2.xml.url</param-name>-->
        <!--<param-value>http://localhot/myrepo/axis2.xml</param-value>-->
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>welcome.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <!-- Security Constraints -->
   <security-constraint>
      <display-name>Tomcat Server Configuration Security Constraint</display-name>
      <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
         <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
         <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
         <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint>
         <role-name>REPACK_Sales_User_Group</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_London_Trade_Support</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_BAC</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_Superusers</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_New_York_Trade_Support</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_Tokyo_Trade_Support</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_Singapore_Trade_Support</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_Sydney_Trade_Support</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_London_Middle_Office</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_New_York_Middle_Office</role-name>
                 <role-name>REPACK_Tokyo_Middle_Office</role-name>
                 <role-name>REPACK_Singapore_Middle_Office</role-name>
                 <role-name>REPACK_Sydney_Middle_Office</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_London_Traders</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_New_York_Traders</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_Tokyo_Traders</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_Singapore_Traders</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_Sydney_Traders</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_London_Business_Manager</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_Legal_Support</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_Legal</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_Credit</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_Trade_Support_Manager</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_GBS</role-name>
         <role-name>REPACK_Bangalore_Support</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
   </security-constraint>

   <!--Change from a pop up dialog box to an input form-->
   <login-config>
      <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
      <realm-name>Repackaging Database - Authentication</realm-name>
      <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/logon.do</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/logon.do?failed=true</form-error-page>
      </form-login-config>
   </login-config>
   <security-role><role-name>REPACK_Sales_User_Group</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_London_Trade_Support</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Superusers</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_BAC</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Credit</role-name>
   </security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_New_York_Trade_Support</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Tokyo_Trade_Support</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Singapore_Trade_Support</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Sydney_Trade_Support</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_London_Middle_Office</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_New_York_Middle_Office</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Tokyo_Middle_Office</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Singapore_Middle_Office</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Sydney_Middle_Office</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_London_Traders</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_New_York_Traders</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Tokyo_Traders</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Singapore_Traders</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Sydney_Traders</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_London_Business_Manager</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Legal_Support</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Legal</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Trade_Support_Manager</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_GBS</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role><role-name>REPACK_Bangalore_Support</role-name>
</security-role>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong order of elements in your web.xml. The error message gives the exact order that the content of your web.xml has to match.

If you check it, at least the `<session-config>` element is in the wrong position (it is before the `<servlet*>` elements, needs to be after). There might be more tags in the wrong position - validate it yourself if you continue to have problems.